# Flutter Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

Hi I'm using flutter on a mac I have to compile a flutter generated kotlin app but I have the following error, how can I fix it?

**Error:**

```
    /annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an
 incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.2.
```

**build.gradle:**

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 31
}
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'

    }
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion 31
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
group 'pt.tribeiro.flutter_pdf_viewer'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems there is a dependency chain from Kotlin 1.8.0 > Gradle 8.0.2 > JDK17. And this warrants updates in the Manifest and build.gradle to migrate to supported syntax. Gradle error suggests using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.